# search filter using searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I'm using searchkick in my rails app. When user types letters of the name he wants to find into form, I get it with params[:query]. The fields' names are (name, login, passwd). The result of searching returns in table. Something like this:

```
env1@something.com login1 passwd1
env1@something.com login2 passwd2
env2@something.com login1 passwd2
env2@something.com login2 passwd2
      ....
```

Searching works fine returning all matched names but the question is how can I get only those fields where the name matches query AND login = login1 for example?

Will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
@users = User.search "*", where: {name: params[:query], login: params[:login]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should help:

```
User.search(params[:query], where: {login: params[:login]})
```